# Right Click and click reload in chrome browser using Selenium in local as well as remote machine

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My requirement is:

1. Go to Chrome
2. Right click and select option. For example I need to click Reload or Back  option in pop up
3. Do the above operation in both, local and a remote PC via Selenium Grid

I was able to achieve the above task using `sendkeys`, but `sendkeys` are only working for current active window. Suppose I started my test on my local PC. On my local PC right click and select option are working.

But on my remote PC, right click alone working but `sendkeys.ARROW_DOWN` or `sendKeys.ENTER` are not working there.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Do you have similar browsers on both machines? Is there any error or just  nothing happen?

Comment: @EugeneS I am having chrome browser with same version in local as well as remote machine. No error is thrown, test step passed. But right click and select option is working in local which is active window and fails on remote which is not active

Comment: I am nor sure what do you mean by "active" and "not active". Can you please elaborate? When you start browser using Selenium Webdriver it always become active by default.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean when you talk about "switching to instance" and "focus on browser". Do you mean you have more than a single instance of WebDriver on a single machine?

Comment: All the selenium commands are working fine in local as well as in remote browser as and when we switch to particular instance in selenium grid, focus is moved on to the particular browser. But SendKeys are not working like this. eg. open browser in local PC -> right click -> arrow down twice-> Click enter once all working fine.  Now open browser on remote PC-> run some selenium commands -> right click -> arrow down twice. But arrow down command is executed in my local PC and not in my remote PC. I am running tests using selenium Grid so two instances comes into picture

Comment: As reload/back is handled by the browser, I'm not sure what this is testing... whether you use right-click or F5 or press the refresh button on the url bar, the same action occurs.

Comment: Why don't you use [driver.refresh() Method](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=refresh#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.refresh)

Comment: My Actual functionality is not clicking reload or back for example i gave, my application is like skype extension for chrome app, my chrome extension has lots of options on right click context menu like add contact, delete contact, call, chat. I need to right click and select an option to make a call or chat. All above mentioned activities are working fine with local, but on remote machine context click working but if i use `sendkeys.ARROW_DOWN` `sendkeys.ENTER` all my commands execute locally, which should be execute on remote

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python implementation of selenium driver, but in c# there is a INavigation object that allows you to perform navigation actions (go back, go forward, refresh)

```
INavigation navigation = driver.Navigate();
navigation.Back();
navigation.Refresh();
```